# R - knitr - span across multiple output pages

Tags: html, r, knitr

I have a long Rmd document which I want to publish across multiple HTML documents (e.g. one page for data cleaning, one for exploratory analysis, one for confirmatory analysis). Is there a way to

- either have knitr output multiple HTML pages from one single Rmd document?
- or split the Rmd document into multiple linked Rmd documents without having to load the data from the previous one?